# Selecting div withing another container w jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a container that has other divs in it. I need to be able to click only the ones that have "clickMe" class in them.

```
<div id="hiddenDiv">
  <div id="val1" class="clickMe">Straight</div>
  <div id="val2">Left</div>
  <div id="somthElse" class="clickMe">Right</div>
</div>
```

It looks quite straight-forward but it does not work for me...

```
$("#hiddenDiv div.clickMe").click(function(){
      ...
}
```

What am I missing?

---

UPDATE:

Not sure what it was, but changing to `$("#hiddenDiv div.clickMe").live("click", function(){` fixed it.

Comment: What behavior are you seeing?

Comment: nothing happens. If I change to $("#hiddenDiv div") then it works fine...

Answer (score 1):

Update:

You will need to fix the quotation that is missing:

`<div id="somthElse" class="clickMe>Right</div>`
is missing the closing quote after clickMe.
`<div id="somthElse" class="clickMe">Right</div>`

The container div is hidden so you can't click it.. Remove the `style="display:none"`

Comment: Oh, ignore that. I took it out. It starts as hidden, later I show it.

Answer (score 1):

You have typos. Try this:

#### HTML

```
<div id="hiddenDiv">
  <div id="val1" class="clickMe">Straight</div>
  <div id="val2">Left</div>
  <div id="somthElse" class="clickMe">Right</div> <!-- Was missing closing 
                                                       quote on class attr -->
</div>​
```

#### Script

```
$("#hiddenDiv div.clickMe").click(function(){
      alert('clicked');
});​ // Was missing closing paren and semi-colon.
```

**Working example**: http://jsfiddle.net/ebFw6/

Answer (score 1):

You missed few little things in your html and js code, though here it is the end result 
http://jsfiddle.net/RZ74s/